# Whether a Prime number can be written as sum of a Prime number and $2^n$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Whether a Prime number greater than can be written as sum of a Prime number and $2^n$?

$P_2 = P_1 +  2^N$

Some Examples of this

$3=2+2^0$
$5=3+2^1$

$1021=509+2^9$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this is not true, as you can discover by looking at the number 127. It cannot be expressed in the required form, and I believe there are more examples.

Edit: Another example is 331, since it is prime, yet all the numbers $331-2^n$ are composite for $n=1, 2,  \dots 8$.

Editt:

There is a [paper available online](http://www.ams.org/proc/2000-128-04/S0002-9939-99-05502-1/S0002-9939-99-05502-1.pdf) by Zhi-Wei Sun in which he gives some background and further examples, and the amazing statement that the integer

$$M = 47867742232066880047611079$$

plus or minus a power of $2$ can never be a prime, although I am not sure if $M$ is itself a prime (although my computer thinks it is likely to be).

Comment: So reverse of it also won't be true for some numbers right? $P_2$=$P_1$-$2^n$

Comment: There's many more examples here: http://oeis.org/A065381

Comment: @Old John That's pretty interesting fact about that integer.

Comment: @Shan Apparently that fact was "observed" by Cohen and Selfridge in 1975. I strongly recommend a read of the paper by Zhi-Wei Sun.

Comment: Sure will do that

Comment: Out of curiosity, what function and software on your computer thinks $M$ is likely to be a prime? Upvoted.

Comment: A pseudoprime test program I wrote many years ago, and have never updated since CPUs got more bits to work with, but still keep handy. I have since checked with pari/gp that it really is prime :)

Comment: John, I forwarded you my email requesting enlightenment from Carl Pomerance. Also to Aaron. I'm back home, still have a cold.